# How to get amazon product (buybox) qty

Tags: amazon-product-api

I have a product named "X" and I'm the only one selling it. The product qty is 482. I've checked junglescout, amztracker and they shows correct product qty. Also, I've checked my other products, and qty is correct. How do they show correct qty? Amazon Product Advertising Api doesn't give this information. Also by parsing amazon product page, you can't give the correct qty. How can I get product qty?

Answer (score 1):

to get stock for your products on amazon you need to use Amazon Reports API and request `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_` report. and for FBA products you need to request `_GET_AFN_INVENTORY_DATA_` report.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it programmatically, you can use AWS API [Carcreate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CartCreate.html) request and add 999 as a qty parameter.

If you want to do it manually using amazon page however, it's pretty much the same. You can add to cart to a specific seller you wanted to check on And then go to your cart and change the value of the qty to 999, it will then reveal the exact value of the stock.

If you want an easy way, there are some good folks who are generous enough to develop a free Chrome extension. One of it is called [stock stats](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stock-stats-amazon-invent/ojlbpinnpcdfahelfllpnommlkfiaoho?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). You may want to check it out.